# Automatically install python modules in EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2

First, sorry if my question is not clear or is too simple, but I'm getting confuse about it. I have an EC2 instance where I want to run some python code previously developed in my computer. I want to automatically install all the packages that the python script use instead of doing `pip` in my EC2 instance for every package. I don't know if I need to use Docker, create a repository in GitHub and then clone it from my EC2 instance, or there is another alternative.

Comment: Generate `requirements.txt` for your code and copy it over, then pip install from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options to go about it.

1. Setup bootstrap to install your packages when you stand up a new EC2 instance.
2. create EC2 instance from image, using docker or with aws AMI.

This will setup an EC2 instance with all the dependency packages ready.